# Undefined ARM vector table

Tags: makefile, arm, bootloader, u-boot

Currently, I'm working with a custom board under U-Boot. I ported all board and vendor specific files into a new U-boot version (v2018) from an older version (v2015). I use a i.MX6UL ARM processor. But by building the project it crash by building of the arm vector table. It says that the instruction are not defined or set.

```
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S: Assembler messages:
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:88: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »b reset«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:88: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr pc,_undefined_instruction«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:88: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr pc,_software_interrupt«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:88: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr pc,_prefetch_abort«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:88: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr pc,_data_abort«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:88: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr pc,_not_used«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:88: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr pc,_irq«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:88: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr pc,_fiq«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:152: Warning: value 0x900020 truncated to 0x20
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:157: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:158: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:159: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:238: Error: Bad parameter list for macro `get_irq_stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:242: Error: Bad parameter list for macro `get_fiq_stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:250: Error: alignment not a power of 2
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r13,IRQ_STACK_START_IN@setup our mode stack«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13]@save caller lr in position 0 of saved stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »mrs lr,spsr@get the spsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: Operand nach »,« erwartet; nichts erhalten
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »msr spsr,r13@switch modes,make sure moves will execute«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Warning: `pc' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: junk `@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' after expression
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Warning: `lr@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' is not valid here (expected `(%rdi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:252: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia sp,{r0 - r12}@Save user registers (now in svc mode)r0-r12«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r2,IRQ_STACK_START_IN«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldmia r2,{r2 - r3}«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia r5,{r0 - r3}@save sp_SVC,lr_SVC,pc,cpsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:253: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:254: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »bl do_undefined_instruction«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:256: Error: alignment not a power of 2
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r13,IRQ_STACK_START_IN@setup our mode stack«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13]@save caller lr in position 0 of saved stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »mrs lr,spsr@get the spsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: Operand nach »,« erwartet; nichts erhalten
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »msr spsr,r13@switch modes,make sure moves will execute«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Warning: `pc' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: junk `@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' after expression
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Warning: `lr@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' is not valid here (expected `(%rdi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:258: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia sp,{r0 - r12}@Save user registers (now in svc mode)r0-r12«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r2,IRQ_STACK_START_IN«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldmia r2,{r2 - r3}«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia r5,{r0 - r3}@save sp_SVC,lr_SVC,pc,cpsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:259: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:260: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »bl do_software_interrupt«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:262: Error: alignment not a power of 2
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r13,IRQ_STACK_START_IN@setup our mode stack«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13]@save caller lr in position 0 of saved stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »mrs lr,spsr@get the spsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: Operand nach »,« erwartet; nichts erhalten
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »msr spsr,r13@switch modes,make sure moves will execute«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Warning: `pc' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: junk `@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' after expression
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Warning: `lr@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' is not valid here (expected `(%rdi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:264: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia sp,{r0 - r12}@Save user registers (now in svc mode)r0-r12«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r2,IRQ_STACK_START_IN«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldmia r2,{r2 - r3}«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia r5,{r0 - r3}@save sp_SVC,lr_SVC,pc,cpsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:265: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:266: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »bl do_prefetch_abort«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:268: Error: alignment not a power of 2
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r13,IRQ_STACK_START_IN@setup our mode stack«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13]@save caller lr in position 0 of saved stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »mrs lr,spsr@get the spsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: Operand nach »,« erwartet; nichts erhalten
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »msr spsr,r13@switch modes,make sure moves will execute«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Warning: `pc' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: junk `@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' after expression
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Warning: `lr@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' is not valid here (expected `(%rdi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:270: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia sp,{r0 - r12}@Save user registers (now in svc mode)r0-r12«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r2,IRQ_STACK_START_IN«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldmia r2,{r2 - r3}«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia r5,{r0 - r3}@save sp_SVC,lr_SVC,pc,cpsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:271: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:272: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »bl do_data_abort«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:274: Error: alignment not a power of 2
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r13,IRQ_STACK_START_IN@setup our mode stack«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13]@save caller lr in position 0 of saved stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »mrs lr,spsr@get the spsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: Operand nach »,« erwartet; nichts erhalten
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »msr spsr,r13@switch modes,make sure moves will execute«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Warning: `pc' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: junk `@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' after expression
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Warning: `lr@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' is not valid here (expected `(%rdi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:276: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia sp,{r0 - r12}@Save user registers (now in svc mode)r0-r12«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r2,IRQ_STACK_START_IN«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldmia r2,{r2 - r3}«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia r5,{r0 - r3}@save sp_SVC,lr_SVC,pc,cpsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:277: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:278: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »bl do_not_used«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:281: Error: alignment not a power of 2
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r13,IRQ_STACK_START_IN@setup our mode stack«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13]@save caller lr in position 0 of saved stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »mrs lr,spsr@get the spsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: Operand nach »,« erwartet; nichts erhalten
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »msr spsr,r13@switch modes,make sure moves will execute«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Warning: `pc' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: junk `@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' after expression
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Warning: `lr@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' is not valid here (expected `(%rdi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:283: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia sp,{r0 - r12}@Save user registers (now in svc mode)r0-r12«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r2,IRQ_STACK_START_IN«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldmia r2,{r2 - r3}«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia r5,{r0 - r3}@save sp_SVC,lr_SVC,pc,cpsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:284: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:285: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »bl do_irq«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:287: Error: alignment not a power of 2
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r13,IRQ_STACK_START_IN@setup our mode stack«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13]@save caller lr in position 0 of saved stack'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »mrs lr,spsr@get the spsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: invalid char '[' beginning operand 2 `[r13'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: Operand nach »,« erwartet; nichts erhalten
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »msr spsr,r13@switch modes,make sure moves will execute«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Warning: `pc' is not valid here (expected `(%rsi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: junk `@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' after expression
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Warning: `lr@jump to next instruction&switch modes.' is not valid here (expected `(%rdi)')
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:289: Error: no instruction mnemonic suffix given and no register operands; can't size instruction
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: too many memory references for `sub'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia sp,{r0 - r12}@Save user registers (now in svc mode)r0-r12«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldr r2,IRQ_STACK_START_IN«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: junk at end of line, first unrecognized character is `@'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »ldmia r2,{r2 - r3}«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: too many memory references for `add'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »stmia r5,{r0 - r3}@save sp_SVC,lr_SVC,pc,cpsr«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:290: Error: too many memory references for `mov'
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:291: Error: Keine solche Anweisung: »bl do_fiq«
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:121: Error: alignment padding (2 bytes) not a multiple of 4
arch/arm/lib/vectors.S:121: Error: alignment padding (2 bytes) not a multiple of 4
scripts/Makefile.build:314: die Regel für Ziel „arch/arm/lib/vectors.o“ scheiterte
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/lib/vectors.o] Fehler 1
Makefile:1410: die Regel für Ziel „arch/arm/lib“ scheiterte
make: *** [arch/arm/lib] Fehler 2
```

Someone have an idea where could be the root of this problem or who would normally set these instructions ?

EDIT 1: 

I changed it to text now, sorry.
Also, I can't imagine that it's a problem with the toolchain itself, 
because I changed to the gcc-6 cause of requirement of the new U-Boot version.
My old U-Boot version (v2015) I can still build with it. So the toolchain itself runs fine in my eyes.

EDIT 2:

It seem to be that **Renaud Pacalet** was right, I used different toolchain now and I got further. The toolchain which I used now is the following: [ARM Cross Compiler](https://www.digikey.com/eewiki/display/linuxonarm/BeagleBone+Black#BeagleBoneBlack-ARMCrossCompiler:GCC) like there described. 

He still dont build everything but that is a different problem cause of the custom board port.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't include pictures of text. It appears you have an issue with your toolchain.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are using the correct assembler? These error messages look a bit like you were assembling ARM code with a MIPS or X86 assembler...